# I am trying to link geographic data and timestamps in R

Tags: javascript, r

I have some data that I am working on for a project that involves plotting data collected from the same location over multiple weeks. I am trying to get a map that only displays the markers that correspond to the date on the time slider, like the leaftime package allows for. However, when I run this code, the markers are all displayed at once, probably because I used the addMarker() in my leaflet map to get popups. So, I am mainly asking if there is a way to either hide markers that do not correspond to the current date on the time slider, or I would like for a way to include popup information on the leaftime markers that are included on the slider. Some example code below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(leaflet)
library(leaftime)

#creating the data frame 
ex_df <- data.frame(location = c('park', 'shopping center', 'school', 'library'),
                latitude = c(50.432543,50.438524,50.445140,50.399818),
                longitude = c(-78.534095, -78.567779,-78.523978,-78.507879),
                count_1 = c(234, 3565, 4, 95),
                count_2 = c(3, 6759, 280, 4820),
                start = c('7/24/1999', '7/31/1999', '8/7/1999','8/19/1999'),
                end = c('7/25/1999','8/1/1999','8/8/1999','8/20/1999'),
                detected = c('detected', 'detected', 'not detected', 'detected'))

#change some of the values to dates and add the week of collection

ex_df<-ex_df %>% 
  mutate(start = mdy(start)) %>% 
  mutate(end = mdy(end)) %>% 
  mutate(week = epiweek(start))
#add the popup
ex_df<-ex_df %>% 
  mutate(popup_tab = paste0("<b>location:<b>",
                    location, "<br>",
                    "<b>count_1:<b>",
                    count_1, "<br>",
                    "<b>count_2: <b>",
                    count_2, "<br>",
                    "<b>detected: <b>",
                    detected, "<br>"))

#change to a geojson object because thats what leaftime wants 
ex_geo <- geojsonio::geojson_json(ex_df, lat = "latitude", lon = "longitude")


#create the leaflet map . 
leaflet(ex_geo) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(data = ex_df,
               lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude,
              label = ~paste0("Week:", week),
               popup = ~popup_tab,
         clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
         ) %>%
  #creates the time slider
  addTimeline(
    sliderOpts = sliderOptions(
      formatOutput = htmlwidgets::JS(
        "function(date) {return new Date(date).toDateString()}"
      ),
    position = "topright",
    step = 4,
    duration = 3000,
    showTicks = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `addMarkers` is the reason why You see all the markers at once. You should remove this layer from Your code. Instead, You need to operate on `timelineOpts` as I'm showing below. I added `setView` which You can customize. The popup now is set inside JS function.

This documentation may be useful for You https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson and this https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup.

```
#create the leaflet map . 
leaflet(ex_geo) %>% 
  setView(lat = 50.42901, lng = -78.53343, zoom = 12) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  #creates the time slider
  addTimeline(
    sliderOpts = sliderOptions(
      formatOutput = htmlwidgets::JS(
        "function(date) {return new Date(date).toDateString()}"
      ),
      position = "topright",
      step = 4,
      duration = 3000,
      showTicks = TRUE),
    timelineOpts = timelineOptions(
      pointToLayer = htmlwidgets::JS(
        "
function(data, latlng) {
  return L.marker(latlng, {}).bindPopup(data.properties.popup_tab)
}
"
      ),
styleOptions = NULL
    )
  )
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you for the assistance and the extra documentation!

Comment: Happy I could help. If the answer solves Your problem please mark it as a solution. Maybe other people will have similar questions in the future